# SSH keygen error (setting up a SFTP server)

Tags: sftp, debian-wheezy, ftp

I was following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-proftpd-to-use-sftp-instead-of-ftp#configure-key-based-authentication), but a problem occurred and I couldn't find any help while googling it.

Whenever I ran the command `sudo ssh-keygen -e -f ~username/.ssh/authorized_keys | sudo tee /etc/proftpd/authorized_keys/username` it outputs only `load failed`.

Can anyone help me setting up and deploying this SFTP server?

I'm using Debian 7.

Comment: On what operating system?  If Linux, us SELinux enabled?

Comment: I edited the question. I'm using Debian 7.

Answer (score 0):

Try just running the ssh-keygen -e -f ~username/.ssh/authorized_keys part.

Do you have anything in your authorized_keys file?

And just to double check you are changing the "username" part to a user on your system.

Comment: That first part returns the error `load failed`.

Comment: I can get it to return load failed on my machine if my authorized_keys file is empty or if I don't have read permission to it.  It gives a key read error if the key is messed up so thats probably not it.

Comment: I'll try to erase the folder and recreate it.

Comment: if you do that make sure to get the perms right.  sshd is very fussy about that.